# List does not show up using For loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

The for loop all the way below is unable to fetch the array list and display it on the page.
Given that both the fruits and directory lists are not functional, it seems that I made a mistake making the for loop.

```
// Data for the "HTML Lists" Page

var fruits = [ "Apples","Oranges","Pears","Grapes","Pineapples","Mangos" ];

var directory = [
    {type: "file", name: "file1.txt"},
    {type: "file", name: "file2.txt"},
    {type: "directory", name: "HTML Files", files: [{type: "file", name: "file1.html"},{type: "file", name: "file2.html"}]},
    {type: "file", name: "file3.txt"},
    {type: "directory", name: "JavaScript Files", files: [{type: "file", name: "file1.js"},{type: "file", name: "file2.js"},{type: "file", name: "file3.js"}]}
];


window.onload=function(){
  // list 1
  var list1 = document.querySelector("#list1");
  var temp1="";
  for (var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
    tmep1+="<li>"+fruits[i]+"</li>";
  }
  list1.innerHTML="<ol>"+temp+"</ol>";
  // list 2
  var list2 = document.querySelector("#list2");
  var list2Text = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < directory.length; i++) {
      if (directory[i].type == "file") {
          list2Text += "<li>" + directory[i].name + "</li>";
      } else {
          var list = "";
          for (var j = 0; j < directory[i].files.length; j++) {
              list += "<li>" + directory[i].files[j].name + "</li>";
          }
          list2Text += "<li>" + directory[i].name + "<ul>" + list + "</ul></li>";
      }
  }
  list2.innerHTML = "<ul>" + list2Text + "</ul>";

}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on what is not functional? I just tried your code and it worked.

Comment: Have you put some `console.log` statements into the function to check 1) The function is actually called. 2) The dom elements are found using `document.querySelector`. I ran this code with some minimal html and it works fine.

Comment: @Kei I am sorry for confusion. Please take a look at the code again.

Comment: Your edit introduced a typo `tmep1`. The original code worked ok why not just use that?

Answer (score 3):

it's just two typos that you have here:

```
for (var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
  tmep1+="<li>"+fruits[i]+"</li>";
}
list1.innerHTML="<ol>"+temp+"</ol>";
```

1- inside the `for` loop, you need to fix `tmep1` to be `temp1`

2- the line after the `for` loop, it's `temp1` instead of `temp`